# "The starting column of the range is too small" error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Here's an example of my script that is working:

```
    function onFormSubmit(e) {
var date = e.values[0];
var user = e.values[1];
var busUnit = e.values[2];
var body = "Request for Add-On form submission" +"\n\n"+"Date:\t\t\t\t"+date +"\n"+ "Employee Email:\t\t"+user +"\n"+"Business Unit:\t\t"+busUnit +"\n\n" +"Form Responses:\t\t" + "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/ID/";

    if (busUnit=="Acme") 
  {
    MailApp.sendEmail("admin@acme.com", "Request for Add-On Submission",body);
    }
    
    if (busUnit=="fakename")
   {
     MailApp.sendEmail("admin@fakename.com", "Request for Add-On Submission",body);
     }
   
   if (busUnit=="fakename2")
   {
     MailApp.sendEmail("admin@fakename.com", "Request for Add-On Submission",body);
     }

}

function getColIndexByName(colName) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var numColumns = sheet.getLastColumn();
  var row = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, numColumns).getValues();
  for (i in row[0]) {
    var name = row[0][i];
    if (name == colName) {
      return parseInt(i) + 1;
    }
  }
  return -1;
}

function emailStatusUpdates() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var row = sheet.getActiveRange().getRowIndex();
  var Email = "alladmins@fakename.com";
  var subject = "Add-On Request Update";
  var body = "The Fake Team has updated the status of the latest request.\n\nStatus: " + sheet.getRange(row, getColIndexByName("approval status")).getValue();
  body += "\n\nRequest: " + sheet.getRange(row, getColIndexByName("What are you requesting to have approved?")).getValue();
  body += "\n\nDescription: " + sheet.getRange(row, getColIndexByName("Provide a brief description")).getValue();
 //body += "\n\nNotes: " + sheet.getRange(row, getColIndexByName("Notes")).getValue();
 //body += "\n\nURL: "+ "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/ID/";

  MailApp.sendEmail(Email, subject, body, {name:"The Fake Team"});
}

function onOpen() {
  var subMenus = [{name:"Send Approval Status", functionName: "emailStatusUpdates"}];
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().addMenu("Send Status Update", subMenus);
}
```

I want to enable the last 2 `body +=` rows. When I do that, I get this error:

> Exception: The starting column of the range is too small.at emailStatusUpdates(Code:45:99)

I tried changing this line to `var row = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, 4, numColumns).getValues();`, but then I get this error:

> Exception: The parameters (number,number,number,number) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange.
> at getColIndexByName(Code:30:19)
> at emailStatusUpdates(Code:45:113)

Comment: What line is the error on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Explanation of errors**

*Exception: The parameters (number,number,number,number) don't match the method*

The method signature for [`getRange`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns) method has only four parameters, in that order:

1. Row to start from
2. Column to start from
3. Number of rows to span (optional, defaults to 1)
4. Number of columns to span (optional, defaults to 1)

The fifths parameter is invalid and the error message clearly states that. What is confusing about the message is that it omits the invalid parameter, but that's on the error handling library used.

*Exception: The starting column of the range is too small*

On the one hand, your `getColIndexByName` function (designed to work similar to [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) method) has two possible return states: a positive `number` ("integer" if we had types in JS) or `-1` on failure to find the `colName` passed as an argument.

On the other hand, `getRange` method accepts only positive `number`s, so in case it is passed a number that is `<= 0`, an error will be thrown. Consider the following example that reproduces the "The starting column of the range is too small" error:

```
function testOutOfRange() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('yourIdHere');
  const sh = ss.getSheets()[0];
  sh.getRange(1, -1);
}
```

<sup>Note: in V8 runtime, the function (at least for my test) just hangs indefinitely. In Rhino runtime, the "desired" error is thrown.</sup>

Since you use the `getColIndexByName` without any guards, the following line blows up if it fails to find the `Notes` column (I assume this is the case because the call works for other column names):

```
body += "\n\nNotes: " + sheet.getRange(row, getColIndexByName("Notes")).getValue();
```

---

**Optimizations**

Your `getColIndexByName` could be reduced down to (note that it would return `0` on no match and still blow up the sendout):

```
function getColIndexByName(colName) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var numColumns = sheet.getLastColumn();
  var row = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, numColumns).getValues()[0];
  return row.indexOf(colName) + 1;
}
```

---

**Applied to the question**

If the assumption that for other column names the script works is true, then the `getColIndexByName` fails to find the `"Name"` column, and given the lack of guards the `emailStatusUpdates` script fails due to parameter constraints violation.

<sup>If that's not true, the answer will be updated</sup>

Comment: Don't mention, glad the issue is resolved - be careful, though, as this only solves the symptom - I like Cooper's approach as you really should not depend on how columns are named to get the desired result. Referencing by location is usually more robust.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
function getColIndexByName(colName) {
  var sh=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var hA=sh.getRange(1,1,1,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
  var idx={};
  hA.forEach(function(h,i){idx[h]=i+1;});
  if(idx.hasOwnProperty(colName)) {
    return idx[colName];
  }else{
    return -1;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Cooper Thanks, but I'm now getting this error after I have added your code: ReferenceError: sh is not defined
    at getColIndexByName(Code:28:31) ```var hA = sheet.getRange(1,1,1,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];```
    at emailStatusUpdates(Code:58:113) ```var body = "The Team has updated the status of the latest request.\n\nStatus: " + sheet.getRange(row, getColIndexByName("approval status")).getValue();```

Comment: Okay sorrry about that.  I have a habit of using short  variables in my code.

Comment: No worries. It's just that I have no idea what hA or idx are.

Comment: Since that was row 1 I assumed it was a header row ...hence hA and idx is an object that will output the array index for a given header.

Comment: If you use these three lines of code in your script: `var hA=sh.getRange(1,1,1,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
  var idx={};
  hA.forEach(function(h,i){idx[h]=i;});` Then you can just use idx['columnName'] all throughout your code without ever having to make and external function call. I do this all of the time for clients that want to be able to add new columns and move them around without blowing up the code.

Comment: Ok. I'm sure what you have down is supposed to work, but I can't figure it out. I'm still getting the ReferenceError: sh is not defined at getColIndexByName(Code:28:31) at emailStatusUpdates(Code:58:113) . Row 1 is the header. I just don't understand. I just want to be able to enable the lines that are commented out, click on the button from the spreadsheet and it will send the information from the columns in the one row that I have listed in the code. The guy who originally wrote the code is no longer around. Thanks anyways man.

Comment: Oh I just realized that you wanted the column number rather that the arrray index because you using getValue().  Sorry about that.